# Maui Resizing community tools popup in c# code

Tags: c#, popup, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm trying to get the size settings by class working as done in MAUI community toolkit samples. They create a class PopupSizeConstants and set the popup-size by

```
Size = popupconstants.medium
```

Unfortunately I can't get the syntax of all the vars passing back and forth to work. Anyone knows of a other sample code using this strategy or has a minimal working code example? The MAUI community toolkit samples is very complex to understand as it hosts multiple popups.

Comment: *" I can't get the syntax of all the vars passing back and forth to work."* - Add to question (as copy/paste text not as image) your attempt at passing vars. And show full text of error message you got. It will help others who may attempt this, to see what you tried, and then see someone's answer that fixes it.

Comment: The popup has a **Size property** and you can custom the size of the popup. Can it meet your requirement?